# How to display Youtube video duration, likes, views

Tags: 7, files

How to extract and display YouTube data like video duration, likes, views in D7 site ?

Comment: There's nothing Drupal-specific about it, you need to use one of YouTube's various APIs

Comment: Have a look at the [Feeds: YouTube Parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_youtube). might helpful?

Comment: I was thining something that would go with any youtube module that displays video from youtube. Many of them have option to paste youtube video link, but none (as far i figured out) parses the data from that link, which would include data from the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the following modules is what you're looking for

[YouTube Pull](https://www.drupal.org/project/youtube_pull)

> YouTube Pull is a simple module to pull YouTube feed for latest video listing. Support any video query parameters by the Youtube API (Atom output format).

```
/**
 * Available variables in the theme is
 * An array of $videos, where each video object has:
 *   $video->title
 *   $video->description
 *   $video->watchURL
 *   $video->thumbnailFull
 *   $video->thumbnailDefault
 *   $video->thumbnailMQ
 *   $video->thumbnailHQ
 *   $video->thumbnailStart
 *   $video->thumbnailMiddle
 *   $video->thumbnailEnd
 *   $video->length
 *   $video->viewCount
 *   $video->rating
 *   $video->commentsURL
 *   $video->commentsCount
 *   $video->responsesURL
 *   $video->relatedURL
 */
```

[Feeds: YouTube Parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_youtube)

> Supported data from imported feeds:
>
> Currently the module supports the following data from imported videos:
>
> - Feed title
> - Video ID
> - Video title
> - Author
> - Updated on (Datetime)
> - Published on
>     (Datetime)
> - Description
> - Thumbnail
> - Category
>     (Can be imported seamlessly with Taxonomy module)
> - Tags (Can
>     be imported seamlessly with Taxonomy module)
> - Watch page URL
>     (Can be imported seamlessly with Embedded Media Field
>     module)
> - Duration (Formatted hh:mm:ss)
> - Favorite
>     count
> - View count
> - Rating